# Centos 5.6 NFS client hangs on file/dir operation on mount, but 10+ other clients (same machine builds) all fine?

Tags: centos, nfs, dell-poweredge

I've got an NFS server which is happily serving out files to 10 NFS clients (and has been doing so for 18 months+).  I recently noticed that one of the clients has stopped working correctly, NFS mounts perfectly fine, but doing any operation on the mount itself results in an endless hang, and frozen terminal.

I've searched around for several hours online and have checked pretty much everything I can, but some info:

- All clients (and server) are the same Dell 2950 machines running
  Centos 5.6/5.7
- All clients are connected to the same local network
- Network connection on both problem client and server is the same
  (1000mb/s Full Duplex), with no connection/latency/packet loss issues
  between them.
- Server responds to rpcinfo, showmount -e and nfsstat straight away
  without issue
- nfs, portmap are installed on the problem client (like all the
  other clients) and started
- Mount works perfectly, returning instantaneously
- I've tried mounting using a variety of mount options (intr, soft,
  nolock)
- Reversing the situation (setting up server on the client, and
  mounting from the server), this works fine!

Can anyone help me out as to something else I could try to resolve this?

Comment: What errors show up if you look at the client-inteface with `ethtool -S eth0` (replace eth0 with your interface)?
You should also start concurrent tcpdump-sessions on a working and on the hanging client. Do you see the same output regarding brodcast and multicast traffic?

Answer (score 0):

can you post a snippit from something like...

> $ cd /broken/nfs/mount
>
> $ strace touch foo

Just curious what syscall it's hanging at.